# Reverse strings in an array

Tags: delphi, for-loop, delphi-strings

```
procedure ReverseArray(var A : array of string);
var I,J,L : integer;
begin
  for I := Low(A) to High(A) do
  begin
    L := length(A[I]);
    for J := L downto 1 do M := M + A[I];
  end;
  writeln(M);
end;


begin
  for I := 1 to 4 do readln(T[I]);
  ReverseArray(T);
  sleep(40000);
end.
```

What I'm trying to do here basically is reverse every string in the array but I'm unable to do it , what the code above do is basically repeat the words depends on their length (I write 'bob' in the array , the procedure will give me 'bob' three times because the length is 3) ... not sure why it's not working properly and what I'm missing

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the **order** of the strings within the array?  Are you trying to reverse the **characters** within each string?  Both?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Your description is a little vague.

Comment: I'm trying to reverse each word , "usa" => "asu"

Comment: Delphi has a [`ReverseString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.ReverseString) function in the `StrUtils` unit.

Comment: Your test data is a palindrome?!!!

Comment: It's not a palindrome . I got it working with the answer above :) thanks guys

Comment: bob is a palindrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is an array of char with some extra bells and whistles added.
So an `array of string` is a lot like an `array of array of char`.
If you want to reverse the string, you'll have to access every char and reverse it.

```
procedure ReverseArray(var A : array of string);
var 
  i,j,Len : integer;
  B: string;
begin
  for i := Low(A) to High(A) do begin
    Len := length(A[i]);
    SetLength(B, Len);  //Make B the same length as A[i].
    //B[Len] = A[i][1]; B[Len-1]:= A[i][2] etc...
    for j := Len downto 1 do B[j]:= A[i][(Len-J)+1];
    //Store the reversed string back in the array.
    A[i]:= B; 
    //Because A is a var parameter it will be returned.
    //Writeln(B); //Write B for debugging purposes.
  end;
end;


var
  i: integer;
  Strings: array [0..3] of string;
begin
  for i := 0 to 3 do readln(Strings[i]);
  ReverseArray(Strings);
  for i := 0 to 3 do writeln(Strings[i]);
  WriteLn('Done, press a key...'); 
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Some tips:

- Do not use global variables like `M` but declare a local variable instead.
- Don't do `AStr:= AStr + AChar` in a loop, if you can avoid it. If you know how long the result is going to be use the `SetLength` trick as shown in the code. It's generates much faster code.
- Instead of a `Sleep` you can use a `ReadLn` to halt a console app. It will continue as soon as you press a key.
- Don't put the `writeln` in your working routine.
- Note the first element in a string is 1, but the first element in a array is 0 (unless otherwise defined); Dynamic arrays always start counting from zero.
- Note that `array of string` in a parameter definition is an [open array](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html); a different thing from a dynamic array.
- Single uppercase identifiers like `T`, `K`, etc are usually used for generic types, you shouldn't use them for normal variables; Use a descriptive name instead.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi has a [`ReverseString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.ReverseString) function in the `StrUtils` unit.

```
uses
  StrUtils;

type
  TStrArray = array of string;

procedure ReverseArray(var A : TStrArray);
var
  I: integer;
begin
  for I := Low(A) to High(A) do
    A[I] := ReverseString(A[I]);
end;

var
  T: TStrArray;
  I: Integer
begin
  SetLength(T, 4);
  for I := 1 to 4 do Readln(T[I]);
  ReverseArray(T);
  ...
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Come on! 'bob' is one of those words you shouldn't try to test a reverse routine. But the problem goes beyond that.

Your problem is in here

```
for J := L downto 1 do 
  M := M + A[I];
```

You are trying to add the whole string to the M variable instead of the character you are trying to access. So, it should be

```
for J := L downto 1 do 
   M := M + A[I][J];
```

Also you need to set `M := ''` inside the first loop where it will have nothing when you start accumulating characters in to it.

Third, move the writing part, `WriteLn(M)`, inside the first loop where you get a nice, separated outputs.

Putting together, it is going to be:

```
for I := Low(A) to High(A) do
begin
    L := length(A[I]);

    M := '';        
    for J := L downto 1 do 
       M := M + A[I][J];

    writeln(M);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution for this is

```
type
  TStringModifier = function(const s: string): string;

procedure ModifyEachOf( var aValues: array of string; aModifier: TStringModifier );
var
  lIdx: Integer;
begin
  for lIdx := Low(aValues) to High(aValues) do
    aValues[lIdx] := aModifier( aValues[lIdx] );
end;
```

and it ends up with

```
var
  MyStrings: array[1..3] of string;
begin
  MyStrings[1] := '123';
  MyStrings[2] := '456';
  MyStrings[3] := '789';

  ModifyEachOf( MyStrings, SysUtils.ReverseString );
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uses
   System.SysUtils, System.StrUtils;

var
   Forwards, backwards : string;

begin
    forwards:= 'abcd';
    backwards:= ReverseString(forwards);
    Writeln(backwards);
    Readln;
end;

// dcba
```

Comment: Please give more explanation even though code is self-explanatory.